# How can i fix STICKY header with grid?

Tags: css, css-grid, sticky

Why when i scroll more than 100% height the strick position doesnt work (header)?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* -------------------- Headers -------------------- */

.social-menu {
  display: none;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav-check {
  display: none;
}

#nav-check:checked~ul {
  display: grid;
}

header nav ul {
  display: none;
}


/* -------------------- Hero -------------------- */

.hero {
  height: auto;
}


/* -------------------- Noticias -------------------- */


/* -------------------- Patrocinadores -------------------- */

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  /* -------------------- Headers -------------------- */
  header nav label {
    display: none;
  }
  #nav-check:checked~ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .social-menu-father {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .social-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 46px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 40px;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .social-menu div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  header nav {
    height: 80px;
  }
  header nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  /* -------------------- Hero -------------------- */
  .hero {
    height: calc(100% - 126px);
  }
  /* -------------------- Noticias -------------------- */
  /* -------------------- Patrocinadores -------------------- */
}
```

```html
  <div class="social-menu-father">
    <div class="social-menu">
      <a href="">Twitch online</a>
      <div>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/08/b5/07/08b5070ece24d17eea517ba0e2b188b4.png" width="50px"></a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
      <label for="nav-check">asd</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Noticias</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Equipos</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Patrocinadores</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Club</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="hero">
    asd
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`body` need to have `min-height` instead. Also replace `height: calc(100% - 126px)` by `height: calc(100vh - 126px)` for the hero header since percentage will no more work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}



.social-menu {
  display: none;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1100px;
}

#nav-check {
  display: none;
}

#nav-check:checked~ul {
  display: grid;
}

header nav ul {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  header nav label {
    display: none;
  }
  #nav-check:checked~ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .social-menu-father {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .social-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 46px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 40px;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .social-menu div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  header nav {
    height: 80px;
  }
  header nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .hero {
    height: calc(100vh - 126px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social-menu-father">
    <div class="social-menu">
      <a href="">Twitch online</a>
      <div>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/08/b5/07/08b5070ece24d17eea517ba0e2b188b4.png" width="50px"></a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
      <label for="nav-check">asd</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Noticias</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Equipos</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Patrocinadores</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Club</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="hero">
    asd
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
```

Setting the body height to 100% will restrict the sticky area to only 100% of the screen height and you will also have overflow. Add some border to better notice this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  border:2px solid;
}



.social-menu {
  display: none;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1100px;
}

#nav-check {
  display: none;
}

#nav-check:checked~ul {
  display: grid;
}

header nav ul {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  header nav label {
    display: none;
  }
  #nav-check:checked~ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .social-menu-father {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .social-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 46px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 40px;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .social-menu div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  header nav {
    height: 80px;
  }
  header nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .hero {
    height: calc(100vh - 126px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social-menu-father">
    <div class="social-menu">
      <a href="">Twitch online</a>
      <div>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
        <a href="">a</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/08/b5/07/08b5070ece24d17eea517ba0e2b188b4.png" width="50px"></a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
      <label for="nav-check">asd</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Noticias</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Equipos</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Patrocinadores</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Club</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="hero">
    asd
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
```